# How to replace specific string in a text file with empty space

Tags: sed

Text file(copyright) having a content like below.

```
gems/1.8/gems/fxri-0.3.6/fxri-0.3.6.tar.gz/fxri-0.3.6.tar/lib/Icon_Loader.rb
misc/common/groovy/groovy-src-1.7.0.tar.gz/groovy-1.7.0.tar/src/examples/swing/RegexCoach.groovy
```

......many more file path like this

I want to replace filename ended with tar.gz to empty space.
expected:

```
gems/1.8/gems/fxri-0.3.6/fxri-0.3.6.tar/lib/Icon_Loader.rb
misc/common/groovy/groovy-1.7.0.tar/src/examples/swing/RegexCoach.groovy
```

This did not work:

```
sed -i -e 's/*.tar.gz//g' copyright
```

Need help.

Answer (score 3):

As a *glob*, `*.tar.gz` means any string ending with `.tar.gz`.  Sed, however, does **not** use *globs*, it uses *regular expressions* and regular expressions have a different syntax.  Try:

```
sed -i -e 's/\/[^/]*\.tar\.gz//g' copyright
```

In the above, the regex `\/` matches anything that starts with `/` (because `/` is being used as the `sed` divider, we escape it as `\/`) followed by `[^/]*` which matches zero or more of any character except `/`, followed by `.tar.gz` where the `.` are escaped so that they match only periods.  (In normal regex notation, `.` matches any one character.)

There are many difference between globs (as used by the shell) and regular expressions (which are used by sed, grep, and other important tools).  In a glob, `.` means a period.  In regex, `.` is a wildcard meaning any single character.  In a glob, `*` means zero or more of any character.  In a regex, `*` means zero of more *of the preceding thing*.

#### Advanced topic

We don't have to use `/` as the divider in a sed substitute command.  Other dividers are possible such as `@`:

```
sed -i -e 's@/[^/]*\.tar\.gz@@g' copyright
```

Because in the above, we use `@` as the dividor instead of `/`, we have no need to escape the first `/`.